# How to check if two files are identical on the same host with ansible ?

Tags: centos, ansible

I use Ansible to manage nodes, and I want to check timezone on my nodes.

I find that on centos, I should replace /etc/localtime by according /usr/share/zoneinfo/{{ timezone }} file.

I write thi task in my ansible playbook :

```
- name: sync timezone file if different
  command: "rsync --itemize-changes --checksum --copy-links /usr/share/zoneinfo/{{ timezone }} /etc/localtime"
```

which works.

My goal is to perform action only if it's necessary, so with this, localtime will be write only if something's changed.

But my problem is that I also want to use Ansible to check any changed on my nodes. And when ansible perform a command, it always marked in report "changed=1", even if there is no change.

I try to use a file modules of ansible, but whether it's to copy remote to local or local to remote, but not remote to remote.

I also try to use a check with register option with this task :

```
- name: Copy timezone {{ timezone }} to /etc/localtime
  shell: "[[ $(md5sum /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris | cut -d' ' -f1) = $(md5sum /etc/localtime | cut -d' ' -f1) ]]"
  register: timezone_check
```

But that's the same problem, command is always execute, so changed is incremented.

Any idea how I could perform this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [override the changed](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result) result.

In your case, you can check the result of your shell command and override the changed status as appropriate.

Full task with override change result :

```
- name: Check timezone conf
  command: "rsync --itemize-changes --checksum --copy-links /usr/share/zoneinfo/{{ timezone }} /etc/localtime"
  register: timezone_check
  changed_when: "timezone_check.stdout.find('>') != -1"
  become: yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create the symlink directly?

```
- name: Set timezone
  file: src=/usr/share/zoneinfo/{{ timezone }} dest=/etc/localtime state=link
```

Comment: I thought of it. But that's not how it is done out of the box. I am not a Linux expert, so I am suspicious about side effect if I create a link instead of copy file. But that's certainly also a solution.

Comment: It has worked perfectly for me and many other people for many years.